# Is there a correct way to make this code work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here I intend to write a program that would calculate parking charges of a vehicle.

The program requires the type of a vehicle, the time in hours and minutes when the vehicle entered the parking plot and time in hours and minutes when the vehicle left the plot. It then calculates the difference between the two timings to calculate the number of hours and minutes for which the vehicle was parked. Finally, it calculates the charges based on the time spent.
Here is what I have coded so far:

```
print (" *****\tA PROGRAM TO CALCULATE PARKING CHARGES OF A VEHICLE\t***** ")
print ('*' * 100)
print ("\tChoose the type of a vehicle you have by pressing the corresponding number.")

type = int (input ("\t1.cars \n\t2.Truck/bus. \n\t3.Scooter/Cycle/Motor cycle.\n>>> "))

while True:
    # Here I intend to check the choice of the type of vehicle the user entered
    # and if the user entered a number more than given options
    flag = 0
    if type > 3:
        print ("The type of vehicle selected is not supported")
        choice = input ("\nWould you wish to continue? (y/n) \n\t>>> ")
        # Here I intend to end the whole program should the user enter 'n'
        if choice.lower() != 'y':
            flag = 1
            pass    
   else:
       # Else the loop should continue until the user choose an option that,
       # Is not less than the given options
       if flag == 0:
           type = int (input ("\t1.cars \n\t2.Truck/bus. \n\t3.Scooter/Cycle/Motor cycle.\n>>> "))
        
else:
    in_hrs = int(input("Enter the time of entrance (HH) : "))
    in_min = int(input("Enter the time of entrance (MM) : "))
    out_hrs = int(input("Enter the time of Leaving (HH) : "))
    out_min = int(input("Enter the time of leaving (MM) : "))

    time_spent = (out_hrs + (out_min/60)) - (in_hrs + (in_min/60))

    if time_spent <= 3:
        if flag == 0:
            if type == 1:
                print(f"Your charges are : {time_spent * 10} £.")
            elif type == 2:
                print(f"Your charges are : {time_spent * 20} £.")
            elif type == 3:
                print(f"Your charges are : {time_spent * 5} £.")
elif time_spent > 3:
        if type == 1:
            print (f"Your charges are : {time_spent * 20} £.")
        elif type == 2:
            print (f"Your charges are : {time_spent * 30} £.")
        elif type == 3:
            print (f"Your charges are : {time_spent * 10} £.")
else:
    print ("The type of Vehicle selected is not supported")


print('*' * 100)
```

The program does not work as I intend it to work and I can't figure out the exact problem, kindly help!

Comment: is this a homework question?

Comment: @novonimo I found this question on a book that I am using to self-taught Python Programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print (" *****\tA PROGRAM TO CALCULATE PARKING CHARGES OF A VEHICLE\t***** ")
print ('*' * 100)
print ("\tChoose the type of a vehicle you have by pressing the corresponding number.")

#type = int (input ("\t1.cars \n\t2.Truck/bus. \n\t3.Scooter/Cycle/Motor cycle.\n>>> "))

cond = True
type = 0
while cond:
    # Here I intend to check the choice of the type of vehicle the user entered
    # and if the user entered a number more than given options
    flag = 0
    if type in [1,2,3]:
        cond = False
    if type > 3:
        print ("The type of vehicle selected is not supported")
        choice = input ("\nWould you wish to continue? (y/n) \n\t>>> ")
        # Here I intend to end the whole program should the user enter 'n'
        if choice.lower() != 'y':
            flag = 1
            
#            pass    
            break
        else:
            type = 0
    else:
       # Else the loop should continue until the user choose an option that,
       # Is not less than the given options
        if type not in [1,2,3]:
            type = int (input ("\t1.cars \n\t2.Truck/bus. \n\t3.Scooter/Cycle/Motor cycle.\n>>> "))
        
else:
    in_hrs = int(input("Enter the time of entrance (HH) : "))
    in_min = int(input("Enter the time of entrance (MM) : "))
    out_hrs = int(input("Enter the time of Leaving (HH) : "))
    out_min = int(input("Enter the time of leaving (MM) : "))

    time_spent = (out_hrs + (out_min/60)) - (in_hrs + (in_min/60))

    if time_spent <= 3:
        if flag == 0:
            if type == 1:
                print(f"Your charges are : {time_spent * 10} £.")
            elif type == 2:
                print(f"Your charges are : {time_spent * 20} £.")
            elif type == 3:
                print(f"Your charges are : {time_spent * 5} £.")
    elif time_spent > 3:
            if type == 1:
                print (f"Your charges are : {time_spent * 20} £.")
            elif type == 2:
                print (f"Your charges are : {time_spent * 30} £.")
            elif type == 3:
                print (f"Your charges are : {time_spent * 10} £.")
    else:
        print ("The type of Vehicle selected is not supported")


print('*' * 100)
```

Comment: There are some changes made in the original code and works like a charm.

Comment: Welcome .. There are some unused variables too.. Since you are learning would be better to fix them by your self :)

Comment: Thank you for noticing that, I will review the code and rectify it.